# Where can I find the list of all queued and non queued Win32 messages?

Tags: windows, winapi

As you know, windows messages are either queued or non queued, based on how they are dispatched. I am interested to know which are queued and which are non queued but I am not able to find that information anywhere yet. The official MSDN documentation [about message routing, here,](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644927%28v=vs.85%29.aspx#routing) although explains the mechanism well, is quite vague when talking about queuedness of messages. It only cites a couple of examples. None of the message specific pages have any information about queuedness either.

Is it deemed an implementation detail that the programmers must not be bothered with beyond the mention that queuedness exist? Any way, for my own curiosity I am looking for such a thing. Does it exist?

Comment: The answer to the question is not practical. stackoverflow.com is for practical programming questions.

Comment: TIL seeking knowledge is not practical.

Answer (score 2):

You usually don't need to know if  a message is queued or not. Also every message may be queued if some one uses PostMessage to send it.

There is only one reason that I can think of: Preprocessing a message before it is dispatched. And this is in nearly 99% used for mouse and keyboard messages (See TranslateMessage and Accelerator and Tooltip message docs).

There are only 3 Groups of messages:

1. Some messages are posted by design: WM_TIMER, WM_PAINT. In fact they are generated when you read the message queue.
2. Then there are all input messages, from Mouse and
   Keyboard. WM_MOUSEMOVE, WM_NCMOUSEMOVE, WM_xBUTTONDOWN,
   WM_xBUTTONUP, WM_xBUTTONDBLCLK, WM_KEYUP, WM_KEYDOWN, WM_CHAR.
3. The large group of IPC functions that are used from OLE, DDE and others.

You can examine this in detail by yourself.  Use Spy++ (32bit/64bit) and watch the messages for a window. The log shows a P for posted messages, and S for SendMessage. R stand for return from SendMessage.

When you use Spy++ you will see that the minority of all messages are placed in the queue.

Again: 
There is no real need to know in detail what messages are send and what are posted.

Comment: `WM_PAINT` messages can be queued or non-queued during normal operation. Calling [RedrawWindow](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd162911.aspx) with a `RDW_UPDATENOW` flag will produce a non-queued `WM_PAINT` message. The 'queuedness' of a message is not an inherent property of a particular message. It is the result of the circumstances that created that message.

Comment: Queued or non-queued only applies to the way the message is handled. It is not a property of the message itself. So, a message may be queued at one time (i.e. posted with PostMessage), and be non-queued another time (send with SendMessage). As xMRi said, there is no point to make such a list.

Comment: I know of the hard way of determining that you described, and other details you talk about. As I've said in my question, I was looking for some article deep in MSDN or some popular forum that may have talked about this. I may not rely on the sent/post -ness of a message to process it but surely no harm in trying to know about it.

Comment: I think my answer is nearly complete wih the coments you have here.

Comment: @thePet: You are still grossly missing the point: There is no list, anywhere, that provides the information you are looking for. You are attributing a property to a message, that is not an attribute of a message. The only list available would be as much made up as your assumption, that the 'queued-ness' is an inherent property of a message type.

Comment: @IInspectable I am not "still grossly missing the point". Look, I see msdn talk about it in relation to messages so thought there may be something more to it. I haven't seen any explicit comment about such information not existing, even in msdn. So, if indeed there isn't then a one liner comment or response would have saved all a lot of time and energy. (And 'queued-ness' is not my assumption, rather a made up word to describe what I was talking about but now thats moot.)

Comment: @thePet: *"windows messages are either queued or non queued, based on how they are dispatched. I am interested to know which are queued and which are non queued"* - and that happens as a **result** of generating a message. It has nothing to do with a particular type of a message. Hence, there is no list. It's also not a result of how they are dispatched. It's the other way around: They are dispatched differently, depending on whether they are queued or non queued.

Comment: All that is fine but I was looking at the _default_ case where the **system** issues a particular message and that message is either queued or not queued, as msdn says. I was looking for Raymond Chen like deep gyan on this topic but that's ok if there isn't.

Comment: @thePet: As I outlined in my very first comment, there usually isn't even a *default* case. The circumstances and topology are important. The particular message type not so much.

Comment: I am not convinced about there not being a default case (and we seem to be going around in circles) but thanks for your time and opinion.